# Does the grappled creature have to be the one that is moved in order to force the grapple to end, or can the grappler be the one that is moved?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, conditions

The description of the [grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled) condition reads, in part:

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature
>   from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a
>   creature is hurled away by the *thunderwave* spell.

For the grappled condition to end, does the grappled creature have to be the one that is moved, or can the grappling creature be the one that is moved?

For example, could a College of Swords bard's [Mobile Flourish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#BladeFlourish-655)* be used to push the grappling creature away, ending the grapple? Or would the bard have to attack the grappled creature with the Mobile Flourish in order to end the grapple in this way?

*Access to *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* in D&D Beyond is required for this link to work.

Comment: I marked your question a duplicate because I felt the linked one asks effectively the same question. If you feel this is not the case though, as always, feel free to [edit] and explain why or drop a comment

Comment: @Medix2 Yes it is a duplicate. I am now convinced that RAW it doesn't matter whether the grappler or grapplee is moved.